# Mock a private method

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock, easymock

I have a method which is private . Now, I do not want to call this private method while doing unit test on `execute()` method. I have tried with PowerMockito and all, but with all type of mockings it still enter into the private method.

Please suggest with workable testcase. Would appreciate the same.

```
@Component 
public class Employee implements SuperClass {

    @Autowired
    private FileTraverse fileTraverse;

    @Override 
    public void execute() throws Exception {
        List<String> traverse = fileTraverse.getFiles();
        Boolean t = isFileTraversed(traverse);
    } 

    private Boolean isFileTraversed(List<String> param1) {
        Boolean flag;
        //do some DB operation and return flag;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can choose mocking framework, youo may try jmockit - which  does  mock private methods

Answer (score 1):

@glytching is right. The best variant it's to extract method in a new service/component and create mock for one. In this case, your code is testable, you can re-use this component ...

BUT in case if you have only one use case for this method and you don't want to create a service/component just for one method, helper method,  you can change the method visibility level from private to protected or package-default. In this case, you can override this method in subclass for testing and work with this sub-class. What you should do : 
create a subclass for the class that you want to test and use the instance of this subclass instead of the target class.

```
--service that you have and need to test one
public class MainService {
    @Autowired
    private SecondService secondService;

    public Object getResultFromMainService(){
        return getResultFromMainServiceFromPrivate();
    }

    --here I changed 'private' into 'default-package' 
    Object getResultFromMainServiceFromPrivate(){
        return secondService.getResult();
    }
}
```

_

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ServiceOverrideTestConfiguration.class)
public class MainServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("subMainService") // or add @Primary and don't use Qualifier
    private MainService service;
    @Autowired
    private SecondService secondService;

    @Test
    public void test(){
        Object result = service.getResultFromMainService();
        --here, method getResultFromMainService call inside the overrided 
            method that we can change
        assertNotNull(result);
    }    
}

@ContextConfiguration
@Import(ApplicationConfigure.class)
class ServiceOverrideTestConfiguration {

    @Bean("subMainService")
    // or add @Primary and don't use Qualifier
    MainService mainServiceSubBean(){
        return new MainServiceUnderTest();
    }
}

class MainServiceUnderTest extends MainService{    
    @Override
    Object getResultFromMainServiceFromPrivate(){
        return "SOME DEFAULT";
    }    
}
```

! Pls, consider this approach only as a workaround in rare cases when you need to mock/stub some method and you can't use PowerMock or any other libs. Better, try to do refactoring and bring testability in your code

Answer (score 1):

Don't mock private methods.

See the suggestion below:

```
@Component 
public class Employee implements SuperClass {

    @Autowired
    private FileTraverse fileTraverse;

    @Override 
    public void execute() throws Exception {
        List<String> traverse = fileTraverse.getFiles();
        Boolean t = isFileTraversed(traverse);
    } 

    private Boolean isFileTraversed(List<String> param1) {
        Boolean flag;
        //do some DB operation and return flag;
    }
}
```

So inside isFileTraversed - you will have a DB operation. This operation will probably be executed through a DAO/Repository object.

So your code will probably look like:

```
@Component 
public class Employee implements SuperClass {

    @Autowired
    private FileTraverse fileTraverse;

    @Autowired
    private DatabaseAccessDao dbAccess;

    @Override 
    public void execute() throws Exception {
        List<String> traverse = fileTraverse.getFiles();
        Boolean t = isFileTraversed(traverse);
    } 

    @Override
    private Boolean isFileTraversed(List<String> param1) {
        Boolean flag;
        flag = dbAccess.checkFileTraversed(param1);
        return flag;
    }
}
```

What you need to do is to mock the public checkFileTraversed() method on the DatabaseAccessDao class.

1) Don't @Autowire on fields - prefer constructor injection.

2) Are you sure you want to return a Boolean? Is "null" allowed as a return value? If not - consider using the primitive boolean type;

Answer (score 0):

Everybody else is right. You should try to avoid mocking private methods as much as you can. And if you really need to mock it, just drop the `private` to put it in default scope.

BUT

For the sake of completeness, you can indeed to it with PowerMock. Here is an example using PowerMock and EasyMock.

```
public class Employee {

  public void execute() {
    // If our mock is working, isFileTraversed will return false
    assertThat(isFileTraversed(Collections.emptyList())).isFalse();
  }

  private Boolean isFileTraversed(List<String> param1) {
    return true;
  }

}

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Employee.class)
public class EmployeeTest {

  @Test
  public void execute() throws Exception {
    Employee employee = PowerMock.createPartialMockForAllMethodsExcept(Employee.class, "execute");

    PowerMock.expectPrivate(employee, "isFileTraversed", Collections.emptyList()).andReturn(false);
    PowerMock.replay(employee);

    employee.execute();

    PowerMock.verify(employee);
  }

}
```